# Flutter : phone verification firebase_auth get error when submit wrong Code

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

why i'm getting error and stuck when i type wrong code in textfield?

```
void _signInWithPhoneNumber(String smsCodes) async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCodes,
    );

    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user =
        await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();

      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SuksesPhone()));
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();

      setState(() {
        canClick = true;
      });
    });
  }
```

but when i type correct code, no error.

the error is like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think it should be like this. When using `await`, you shouldn't use `then`.

```
void _signInWithPhoneNumber(String smsCodes) async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCodes,
    );

    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    final FirebaseUser user =
        await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).catchError((onError{
          //do something           
        }));

        //check user  
if(user){

      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SuksesPhone()));
}
  }
```